# Bootstrap Scrollspy Error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I'm putting some documentation together using Bootstrap and running into an issue with the Scrollspy plugin in Firefox. Essentially, the "active" class is getting appended to the last list item in my sidebar nav and won't change, even upon scrolling through the page.

I have compared my example with Bootstrap's version and cannot determine any discrepancies between the two. The script works in all other browsers, including IE8+.

I've hosted my working example of it here for anyone to take a look at if you have the time (the page source is very simple, so it's probably just easier looking at it here in Firefox than in a jsFiddle or something): http://dev.themusicake.com/

Documentation on Scrollspy can be found here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

I am using the data attributes on the `<body>` element as is suggested:

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".nav-affix-container">
```

There aren't any errors being thrown in the console either, adding to the troubles of figuring out the issue. If anyone has had any issues with this particular problem in the past, any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Please let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `height: 100%` from `body`.

Comment: It's always the little things. ;) Feeling goofy for overlooking such a little thing, but very appreciative for your help. Thanks, SilentGhost!

Comment: are there advantages to having `height: 100%` ?

Comment: Yes, it is required i.e. for a [Sticky Footer](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer-navbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that i used float:left on the content div, which results in an height = 0 on the content itself. Therefor the scrollspy won't be able to identify the height(i guess?)

I simply used clear both below the content div to fix the problem.

```
 <br style="clear: both"/>
```